# Tempus Date-Time-Picker how to get date

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm new on PHP and everything in general, I'm building an application where a date picker is shown. I want to submit the date following a specific format (year : "y" and month : "m") to end up with a url like http://localhost/index.php?m=06&y=2019...

the datepicker i'm using is https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/

and the code:

HTML:

```
                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 col-12">                         
                            <div class="float-left">
                                <form action="">
                                    <div class="input-group">                                        
                                        <input name="datepicker" id="datepicker" class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 borderdate-pickerwidth:auto" value="04/01/2021" />
                                        <button class="input-group-append">
                                            <i class="mdi mdi-calendar align-middle font-c-x-large border-left-0 border px-2"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    });
});
```

Actually if I submit a form the value is:

```
?datepicker=04%2F01%2F2021
```

but I want:

```
?m=01&y=2021
```

So my question is: How can I submit the information displayed on the datepicker and format it as commented above?

Thank you in advice.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with any of the picker options. Taking a single input and creating several variables from it requires manual work. May I ask why would you want this? If you need it purely for processing, then you can easily extract individual values (year, month, day) in the code that processes the submit.

Comment: Hello, firstly thank you for your answer, I would like to process some values from the page content depending on the month/year selected (let's say for example, monthly visitors). I found a solution which consist of 2 different inputs with different values, but I would like to make it more simple... How could I extract the individual values? maybe  with php explode?

Comment: It's best to use the [`DateTime` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). First you create the object through `createFromFormat` and then you can use `format` to extract any individual piece of information like month, year or whatever you need.

Comment: Cool! Thank you for your answer. I'm also new on stackoverflow, so.. should I upvote this comment?

Comment: No action is required on your part here. You only need to consider voting and accepting if the question gets answered. Which I don't feel is necessary here if you've solved your problem by using a suggestion from the comment.